# Why findOneAndUpdate runs .then even if returned object was null? Mongoose

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

This is my code:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { confirmationToken: "blablabla" },
    { confirmationToken: "", confirmed: true },
    { new: true }
    )
    .then(user => res.json({ user: user.toAuthJSON() }) )
    .catch(err => res.json({ err }));
)
```

When there isn't any user with such confirmationToken, findOneAndUpdate returns null but why it runs .then instead of .catch? Shloudn't it run .then when user is returned and run .catch when returned is NULL instead of user object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning `null` is valid response. To protect your code from that you could:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { confirmationToken: "blablabla" },
    { confirmationToken: "", confirmed: true },
    { new: true }
    )
    .then(user => res.json({ user: user ? user.toAuthJSON() : user }) )
    .catch(err => res.json({ err }));
)
```

Or you could `throw` inside your `.then` if hitting the catch is what you really want.

As per mongoose docs on [Model.findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate):

> Finds a matching document, updates it according to the update arg,
>   passing any options, and returns the found document **(if any)** to the
>   callback.

Answer (score 0):

`catch` runs when an error occurred, for example:
 Error in mongoose validation or when you want update a document in collection and some errors occurred.